ArgumentOutOfRangeException error while assigning OracleClob value to .NET Core string
I want to read large clob data type (2 million rows in table) from a stored procedure in an Oracle database. After reading the data and trying to assign OracleClob value field to .NET Core string type, I get the following exception errors:

ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error

and

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Arg_ParamName_Name

This is what I have done:
OracleParameter clobParameter = new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "o_OutVal",
                            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                        };
command.Parameters.Add(clobParameter);


OracleClob oracleClob = (OracleClob)command.Parameters["o_OutVal"].Value;

string text = oracleClob.Value;
File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, text);

